# Formatting of defined terms

Tags: meaning, terminology, word-formation

In my report, I am defining/describing some terms. What is a proper way to start and format a sentences like:

> The term crawling denotes the practice of ...

Should I put the word/term *crawling* in quotes, bold, italic, or something else?

I think

> The term "crawling" denotes the practice of ...

looks a bit ugly but is probably easier to read.

On Wikipedia, most terms seem to be formatted in bold font.

Answer (score 0):

Obey your manual of style, either the one you choose or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which notes that different fields (mathematics, ethnography, etc.) have different styles.  In general, for ordinary words used in a specialized sense, they recommend enclosing the word in quotes.

Comment: I am using the APA style but I don't know what to look for in the style guide relevant for my case

Comment: Go here: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/04/using-italics-for-technical-or-key-terms.html